# Uso de un booleano para un bucle

Tags: java, while

tengo un método que pide un entero y donde declaro una excepción propia si el valor no es validado, tengo un problema de lógica ya que no me está funcionando el bucle que debe volver a pedir el valor cuando no se cumpla la condición, no entiendo el porqué, dejo el código:

```
 public void setEdad() throws CustomException.EdadIncorrecta{
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repetir=true;
    
    do{System.out.println("Ingrese edad: ");        

        int edad = teclado.nextInt();   
        
        if (edad < 1 || edad > 110) {

        throw new CustomException.EdadIncorrecta("La edad no puede ser menor a 1 ni mayor a 110");

        }else           
            this.edad = edad;
            repetir = false;

            
}while(!repetir);
}
```

Comment: pon el error que te dá, no todos tienen un compilador incluido.

Comment: No me da ningún error, o en todo caso, el error es que no cumple su función, no ejecuta el bucle cada vez que se ingresan valores incorrectos

Comment: porque se sale siem´pre después de la primera iteración?

Comment: Esa sería mi pregunta, cuando ingreso valores validos (enteros de 1 a 110), es correcto que se salga, pero cuando los valores no son validos debería volver a iterar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `else` debe tener llaves para agrupar las dos instrucciones que le corresponden. Y ese método no debe lanzar una excepción ante una edad inválida, para eso se ha colocado un while de validación. Las excepciones son para casos "excepcionales" y una entrada incorrecta no lo es.

```
public void setEdad() {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repetir = true;

    do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese edad: ");

        int edad = teclado.nextInt();

        if (edad < 1 || edad > 110) {

            System.out.println("Edad incorrecta.");

        } else {
            this.edad = edad;
            repetir = false;
        }


    } while (repetir);
}
```

Comment: Genial, gracias como siempre :)